# rxjs - single observable for multiple inputs or an observable per input

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I was wondering if there were any negative reasons for using a single observable to track multiple input fields. The only problem I've really come across from doing this is that I can't really use `distinctUntilChanged` because there are cases where the text may end up overlapping, which means it doesn't trigger.

Example of my single observable:

```
this.subscription = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($(joined), 'keyup')
        .pluck('target')
        .flatMap(target=>
             Rx.Observable.of(target.value)
             .filter( (text) => {
                  text = text.trim();
                  if (!text.length) // empty input field
                  {
                      this.setState({
                        list: {
                          company: [],
                          country: [],
                          state: [],
                          suburb: [],
                          street: []
                        }
                      });
                  }
                  return text.length > 0;
              })
              .map(response => ({
                  id: target.id.replace("_input", ""),
                  term: target.value
              }))
        )
        .debounceTime(200)
        .switchMap(r => this.search_type(r.term, r.id))
        .subscribe(
            /* some code */
        )
```

Would it be alright if i just stuck to a single observable or should I have an observable per input?

Comment: If I were on a team with this code the intent might be lost. If it's just you developing it, it looks sound to me and I would use it. But if you're on a team, you might go ahead and have an observable per input because I think the intent is clearer, it's the same function for each (so not much overhead added), but as soon as one is different you have a hook into it. But this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on the situation. 
Lets say we have two inputs firstName, lastName . I want to be able to search in any of the fields and so if you enter 'john' in firstName or 'john' in lastname it results in same result and rightfully so.

If you want different result , then you can convert your query adding source of input too . That way first queryparam would be `{firstnameQuery: 'john'}` and second one `{lastnameQuery: 'john'}` since these two are different there wont be any issue.

If each input has different search trigger , then there is no point in clubbing them together.

Comment: The second paragraph is what my `.switchMap(r => this.search_type(r.term, r.id))` is doing. the `search_type` basically differentiates the part it's searching for.